# Netcat on MacOS failing with simple commands

Tags: mac-osx, netcat, zsh

I'n trying to follow a tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@Proclus/reverse-bind-shells-for-everyoned-e7507853bf4e).

> As an example we can say that we need a friend of ours to help us with something on our work system(Windows). To be able to receive a connection from us first our friend would need to set up a listener. `nc -lvnp 4444`

On my system, `nc -nlvp 4444` fails with `nc: missing port with option -l`. I'm not sure why this is, as I've seen multiple tutorials with the same commands and it works fine. Is this a MacOS issue, or is it between keyboard and chair?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic. We don't accept general computer questions. You may be able to get help on one of our sister sites, such as [apple.se] or [su].

Comment: The `nc` command isn't particularly portable, and the version on macOS takes slightly different options than the GNU version that command's probably intended for. Check the `man` page.

Comment: I had some similar issue in the past with NC and fixed it by `nc -nvp -l 4444` don't know why it seems to be a general issue